# Бот перестаёт отвечать

Tags: java, discord-api

Создавал бота для дискорда на java, вроде всё пошло, но при запуске вылетает следующий warning:

```
 Discord4J: ERROR INITIALIZING LOGGER!
Discord4J: No SLF4J implementation found, reverting to the internal implementation (sx.blah.discord.Discord4J$Discord4JLogger)
Discord4J: It is *highly* recommended to use an full featured implementation like logback!
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

Однако, бот подключается и исправно работает, но через некоторое время он просто перестаёт откликаться на мои запросы, хотя консоль показывает, что бот работает ( запускал его в скрине на VDS ). В чём может быть ошибка?

pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>bottest</groupId>
    <artifactId>bottest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.austinv11</groupId>
            <artifactId>Discord4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bottest</groupId>
            <artifactId>bottest</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Сам код бота.

```
package ru.frostdelta.bot;

import org.json.JSONException;
import sx.blah.discord.api.ClientBuilder;
import sx.blah.discord.api.IDiscordClient;
import sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher;
import sx.blah.discord.api.events.IListener;
import sx.blah.discord.handle.impl.events.MessageReceivedEvent;
import sx.blah.discord.handle.obj.IChannel;
import sx.blah.discord.handle.obj.IMessage;
import sx.blah.discord.util.DiscordException;
import sx.blah.discord.util.MessageBuilder;
import sx.blah.discord.util.MissingPermissionsException;
import sx.blah.discord.util.RateLimitException;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;



public class EchoBot implements IListener<MessageReceivedEvent> {

    public static final String ECHO_BOT_TOKEN = "MzU2ODM4OTA1NTk0NzczNTE1.DOudlg.mrtlBoueIa-Wm6eoHMSwUtEqWtM";
    private IDiscordClient dscordClient;
    private boolean isConnected;
    private String inputMsgStr;
    private String result = "test123";
    private IChannel channel;


    private void regBot() {
        EventDispatcher dispatcher = dscordClient.getDispatcher();
        dispatcher.registerListener(this);
    }
    public void login() throws DiscordException {
        ClientBuilder cBuilder = new ClientBuilder();
        cBuilder.withToken(EchoBot.ECHO_BOT_TOKEN);
        dscordClient = cBuilder.login();
        regBot();
        this.isConnected = true;
    }


    public void handle(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        IMessage message = event.getMessage();
        IChannel channel = message.getChannel();
        inputMsgStr = message.getContent();
        try {
            result = ((JsonNode) Unirest.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=578080&currency=5&market_hash_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(inputMsgStr, "UTF-8")).asJson().getBody()).getObject().getString("median_price");
            new MessageBuilder(this.dscordClient).withChannel(channel).withContent(result).build();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DiscordException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RateLimitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MissingPermissionsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EchoBot echoDiscordBot = new EchoBot();
        try {
            echoDiscordBot.login();
            System.out.println("Бот успешно подключен.");
        } catch (DiscordException e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка при подключении бота к Discord: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: включите логи путем добавления зависимости. Проблема не в самих логах, но логи помогут понять проблему

Answer (score 0):

Согласно логу ошибки у вас не хватает зависимости на slf4j:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
</dependency>
```